# Restrict my pages from public

Tags: plugins, customization, pages, user-access

In my site I want to restrict some pages from public.
How can I do this?

```
    example : www.xyz.com/members
```

This pages only access when the user is log in but now its access public also using coping that url.

If any plugins available in this?

Comment: It depends on how you want to lock out users of different types. I usually lock out members sections by checking if the user is on one of the locked pages, either by a list of URL's, page parent or by the page-template. Then if they aren't logged in using [wp_reditrect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) to force them to the login page. this code is stuck in the header.php as the very first thing.

Comment: @Chris Morris thanks for your response ,so we want to check all pages if user is log in or not

Comment: How will users be logging into the website, are you using the standard word press login page or are you using a plugin to style a login page?

Comment: No I am using custom Jquery pop up login